# Principal bundles in the sense of Cartan and Steenrod.

Tags: algebraic-topology, vector-bundles, noncommutative-geometry

i am starting to learn Noncommutative Geometry, but I did not attend course of Algebraic Topology during studies. For next week I need to know what is principal bundle, in both senses of Cartan and Steenrod. Do You know where it is well explained?

And more generally, do You know any Algebraic Topology book which will be good for person who wants to use it as a tool (in NCG in my case), not to study it as a main domain of interest?

Comment: https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/principal+bundle#InTopologicalSpaces

Comment: There is a principal bundle in the sens of Cartan, but  not in Steenrode. Practically, when I google "principal bundle in the sense of Steenrode" nothing appears.

Comment: Probably your professor by "principal bundle in the sense of Steenrod" means the definition that is in the Steenrod's book i.e. The topology of Fibre bundles.